# App/Utility for viewing files on Android phone memory?

Tags: android, file, rooted-device

Is there some utility available that will display all the files on an android phone, including local memory and sd card, even if the phone is not rooted?

It could be either some Android app or some PC-based utility that would display the files on a phone connected via USB.

Also, for those of you who develop on android phones, do you do your development and testing on rooted phones?

Answer (score 0):

There's the [Android Device Monitor](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/monitor.html) that ships with the SDK. It's integrated into Android Studio and Eclipse.

Let's you inspect the file system and a lot more. I've only ever used it with simulators. Non rooted phones won't display their /data/data directory, from the ones I have. You'd have to root them for that, I believe.